# Appropriate algorithm for offline bidirectional data synchronization

Tags: synchronization, offline, relational, bidirectional, mvcc

Given:

- Relational database table information (postgres) that represents company information and user information.
- The company and user data is downloaded to the mobile app as two .sqlite files, which can be joined and viewed using sql (minimizes data manipulation)

Question:

How can we enable the user data to be updated offline, and sync'd, but still allow us to join the data using SQL across the company and user sqlite databases?

Answer?:

I think what we want is an algorithm to do the sync'ing. I've looked at MVCC with seemingly the [best write-up on implementation here](https://epxx.co/artigos/arqtrans2_en.html).

However, from this, it looks like joining across the two databases looks murky (with having to store version info in the rows --- but maybe I'm wrong).

Ideally:

- Able to join data across db's relatively easily.
- Whether the solution is generic or not in unimportant, but something that's relatively easy to apply similarly to other data type / tables is helpful.
- No conflicts: "most recently updated wins" works

I imagined storing a custom transaction table and applying that, but figured somebody had worked out the details?

Notes:

- I realize Couchbase supports this, but we'd rather not have a relational and document store.
- Is MVCC "overkill"?